# How to Send a Feature to a Different Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, layers

I have a polygon that I made using the buffer tool on a layer. The problem is, I can't figure out how to send this polygon to the layer I would like it to be on. The yellow polyon is the one I'm trying to move, and I'm trying to move it to the red layer. How can I do this using ArcGIS 10.1 for desktop? [image]

Comment: Are you looking to merge them into one feature class?

Comment: @MyFamily Yeah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Append](http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/spring12articles/storm-water-revenue-management-system.html) may be what you are looking for. You should be able to select the polygon you want to move from the yellow layer and append it to the existing red layer.

Comment: @EmilyF This is the tool you are looking for